Issues with Animation Flickering and Color Artifacts in STM32 SSD1331 using Double Buffering
I’m new to C programming language and working with STM32 microcontrollers, so I apologize in advance for any trivial or naive questions.
I’ve been working on an animation for an SSD1331 OLED display using STM32. I wrote a function called ssd1331_draw_animation that works fine for the most part, but there is one strange issue: the animated bitmap flickers. Everything seems to work as expected except for this flickering behavior.
To fix this, I decided to implement double buffering, hoping that it would eliminate the flickering. However, after introducing double buffering, I started encountering another problem: the bitmap begins to change colors and the entire display starts showing strange artifacts so i reverted back to my program without it. Have you got any ideas how to fix this or implement double buffering propely?
Here is my function without double buffering:
uint8_t ssd1331_check_exposed_pixel(uint8_t x_min, uint8_t x_max, uint8_t y_min, uint8_t y_max, uint8_t pixel_value, uint8_t xppos, uint8_t yppos){
    if(xppos > x_max || xppos < x_min || yppos > y_max || yppos < y_min || pixel_value == 0x00){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
void ssd1331_draw_animation(uint8_t new_chXpos, uint8_t new_chYpos, uint8_t old_chXpos, uint8_t old_chYpos, const uint8_t *pchBmp, const uint8_t * pBackBmp, uint8_t chWidth, uint8_t chHeight){

    ssd1331_draw_bitmap(new_chXpos, new_chYpos, pchBmp, chWidth, chHeight, 0);
    uint16_t i, j;
    int16_t deltaX = (int16_t)(new_chXpos - old_chXpos);
    int16_t deltaY = (int16_t)(new_chYpos - old_chYpos);


    for(j = 0; j < chHeight + ((deltaY < 0) ? -deltaY : deltaY); j++){
        for(i = 0; i < chWidth + ((deltaX < 0) ? -deltaX : deltaX); i++){

            uint16_t x = (deltaX < 0) ? (uint16_t)(new_chXpos + i) : (uint16_t)(old_chXpos + i);
            uint16_t y = (deltaY < 0) ? (uint16_t)(new_chYpos + j) : (uint16_t)(old_chYpos + j);

            int16_t local_x = (int16_t)(x - new_chXpos);
            int16_t local_y = (int16_t)(y - new_chYpos);

            if (local_x >= 0 && local_x < chWidth && local_y >= 0 && local_y < chHeight) {
                uint16_t pixel_value = (uint16_t)((pchBmp[(local_y * chWidth + local_x) * 2] << 8)
                        | pchBmp[(local_y * chWidth + local_x) * 2 + 1]);


            if(ssd1331_check_exposed_pixel( ((deltaX > 0) ? (uint16_t)old_chXpos : (uint16_t)new_chXpos),
                                            ((deltaX > 0) ? (uint16_t)new_chXpos : (uint16_t)old_chXpos),
                                            ((deltaY > 0) ? (uint16_t)old_chYpos : (uint16_t)new_chYpos),
                                            ((deltaY > 0) ? (uint16_t)new_chYpos : (uint16_t)old_chYpos),
                                            pixel_value,
                                            x, y) ){
                uint16_t back_pixel = (uint16_t)((pBackBmp[(y * OLED_WIDTH + x) * 2] << 8) | pBackBmp[(y * OLED_WIDTH + x) * 2 + 1]);
                ssd1331_draw_point(x, y, back_pixel);
            }

        }
    }


}
}

How can i fix this?
Note: Other functions in use:
void ssd1331_draw_bitmap(uint8_t chXpos, uint8_t chYpos, const uint8_t *pchBmp, uint8_t chWidth, uint8_t chHeight, uint16_t hwColor)
{
    uint16_t i, j;


    for(j = 0; j < chHeight; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < chWidth; i++) {

            uint16_t pixelIndex = (j * chWidth + i) * 2;
            uint16_t color = (pchBmp[pixelIndex] << 8) | pchBmp[pixelIndex + 1];

            if(color != 0x0000)
                ssd1331_draw_point(chXpos + i, chYpos + j, color);
        }
    }
}

void ssd1331_draw_point(uint8_t chXpos, uint8_t chYpos, uint16_t hwColor) 
{
    if (chXpos >= OLED_WIDTH || chYpos >= OLED_HEIGHT) {
        return;
    }

    //set column point
    ssd1331_write_byte(SET_COLUMN_ADDRESS, SSD1331_CMD);
    ssd1331_write_byte(chXpos, SSD1331_CMD);
    ssd1331_write_byte(OLED_WIDTH - 1, SSD1331_CMD);
    //set row point
    ssd1331_write_byte(SET_ROW_ADDRESS, SSD1331_CMD);
    ssd1331_write_byte(chYpos, SSD1331_CMD);
    ssd1331_write_byte(OLED_HEIGHT - 1, SSD1331_CMD);
    
    //fill 16bit colour
    ssd1331_write_byte(hwColor >> 8, SSD1331_DATA);
    ssd1331_write_byte(hwColor, SSD1331_DATA);   
}

static void ssd1331_write_byte(uint8_t chData, uint8_t chCmd) 
{
    if (chCmd) {
        __SSD1331_DC_SET();
    } else {
        __SSD1331_DC_CLR();
    }
    
    __SSD1331_CS_CLR();
    __SSD1331_WRITE_BYTE(chData);
    
    __SSD1331_CS_SET();
    __SSD1331_DC_SET();
}

#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "SSD1331.h"
#include "grass_texture.h"
#include "golf_logo.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim10;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/*
 * ADC_Buffer[0] --> The x coordinate from joystick input
 * ADC_Buffer[1] --> The y coordinate from joystick input
 * ADC_Buffer[2] --> The Signal A from encoder input
 * ADC_Buffer[3] --> The Signal B from encoder input
 */

uint16_t ADC_Buffer[4];
uint8_t frame_update;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM10_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint8_t level = 0;
    uint8_t game_is_running = 1;
    uint8_t i, j = 4;

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM10_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    //ADC1/TIM2/OLED INICIALIZATION
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim10);


    if (HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*) ADC_Buffer, 4) != HAL_OK)
        Error_Handler();

    ssd1331_init();
    ssd1331_draw_bitmap(0, 0, image_data_grass_texture, 96, 64, 0);
    //ssd1331_draw_bitmap(16, 4, image_data_golf_logo, 64, 15, 0);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (game_is_running) {
        switch (level) {

        case 0:
            uint8_t lg_flag = 0;

            while (level == 0) {
                if (frame_update) {
                    if ((i < 9) && (lg_flag == 0)) {
                        i++;
                        //ssd1331_draw_animation(16, i, 16, j, image_data_golf_logo, image_data_grass_texture, 64, 15);
                        ssd1331_draw_animation(16, i, 16, j,
                                image_data_golf_logo, image_data_grass_texture,
                                64, 15);
                        j = i;
                        frame_update = 0;
                    } else {
                        lg_flag = 1;
                        j--;
                        ssd1331_draw_animation(16, j, 16, i,
                                image_data_golf_logo, image_data_grass_texture,
                                64, 15);
                        frame_update = 0;
                        i = j;
                        if ((i >= 4) && (i < 5))
                            lg_flag = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
            break;
        };

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }

  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim->Instance == TIM10) {
        frame_update = 1;
    }
}

Partly repaired function (with leftover pixels):
ssd1331_check_exposed_pixel(
    ((deltaX > 0) ? (uint16_t)old_chXpos : (uint16_t)new_chXpos),
    ((deltaX > 0) ? (uint16_t)new_chXpos + chWidth : (uint16_t)old_chXpos + chWidth),
    ((deltaY > 0) ? (uint16_t)old_chYpos : (uint16_t)new_chYpos),
    ((deltaY > 0) ? (uint16_t)new_chYpos + chHeight : (uint16_t)old_chYpos + chHeight),
    pixel_value,
    x, y
);


Double Buffering: I attempted to create a second frame buffer to write to the display first and then swap it. This should have resolved the flickering.
Color Artifacts: After implementing double buffering, the bitmap colors are not displayed correctly. Instead of showing the intended colors, strange artifacts appear on the screen, and the animation becomes corrupted.

How do you transfer the whole thing to the OLED, SPI over DMA?

@Lundin i set frame_update flag with timer tim10 to transfer it. I will add my main function to the post

If I comment out the following lines:
uint16_t back_pixel = (pBackBmp[(y * OLED_WIDTH + x) * 2] << 8) | pBackBmp[(y * OLED_WIDTH + x) * 2 + 1];
ssd1331_draw_point(x, y, back_pixel);
the flickering effect disappears. However, the previous texture remains in its old position, resulting in an overwrite effect on the screen.

There's a whole lot of small integer arithmetic in this code, which is always a bad idea due to integer promotion. And because of that, pretty much all arithmetic here comes with some serious code smell since most of it is carried out on 32 bit signed int, which isn't a type you actually intended to use in any of the expressions.

@Ludin, thanks for your answer. However, even after typecasting the variables, I still get the refreshing effect on the animated bitmap. I will update the code above, but maybe I am missing something or not fully understanding what you meant.

Most of those casts are pointless and achieve nothing. Maybe have a peek at Implicit type promotion rules

@EricPostpischil Apologies for not presenting the problem clearly enough earlier. The issue I’m facing is flickering of the animated bitmap in the function without double buffering. My previous implementation using double buffering was completely broken, so I’ve reverted to this version which at least does not have artifacts.

You're doing a massive amount of work for each pixel you want to draw, including sending the column and row address for every pixel. More normal would be to do all your "rendering" into a RAM framebuffer, then send the entire thing to the display in one go using DMA.

Alright, I will try using DMA in that case, and thank you for the response. However, it turned out that the reason for the bitmap flickering was incorrectly passing parameters to the ssd1331_check_exposed_pixel function, which caused all pixels to be read as "exposed" and painted with the background color. My corrected version is on note in edited post. However, now I've encountered another issue with leftover individual pixels in the bitmap color appearing where they shouldn't be anymore... I'll try sending data via DMA as you suggested. Thanks again for the response!

what is __SSD1331_WRITE_BYTE? where and how the SPI was initialized?
